# mongodbrestore + drop + nsexclude does not work

Tags: mongodb

I try to :
1 - clear my local mongodb, except one collection
2 - restore the database from my backup, except one collection

I use the following command

```
mongorestore ./dump_prod --gzip --drop --nsExclude 'MyDatabase.IdentityServerClients'
```

The problem is that all the collections are restored, IdentityServerClients is overwritten!

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Is MyDatabase the name of the database in the dump or restore destination?

Comment: "MyDatabase" is the database name, So I have this file "/dump_prod/MyDatabase/IdentityServerClients.bson" by example :-)